# Unable to select Row of Tableview While using ReverseExtension framework

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reverse

I am Implemented a messaging application in the there a conversation or chat room in that room there is some attachments along with text messages the entire thing implemented with the help of UItableview and reverse extension for showing data from the bottom like whatsapp upto here working fine for me. But while tapping or selecting the attachment row  the tableview view "didSelect Row At IndexPath" method not calling why.

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there would be much easier (and more direct) ways to do "fill from bottom" table views, but...

In the ReverseExtension framework files, open `ReverseExtension.swift`, find:

```
extension UITableView.ReverseExtension: UITableViewDelegate {
```

and add this to that block:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let delegate = delegate {
        let newIndexPath: IndexPath = reversedIndexPath(with: indexPath, fromReversed: true)
        delegate.tableView?(tableView, didSelectRowAt: newIndexPath)
    }
}
```

**Important Note**: this is from a *very* quick look at the source, and it is entirely possible that it could cause issues with the rest of the framework -- which may be why it is not there to begin with.

But - quick testing doesn't appear to cause any conflicts.